# Update celery beat schedule at runtime

Tags: python, celery, celerybeat

As far as I've seen, the native implementation of celery beat scheduler does not provide a way of adding and syncing scheduled tasks at runtime. There is django-celery-beat, but I do not want to add django dependency (which I don't really need).

I have found a couple of third-party packages backed by Redis (celery-redbeat, redisbeat);

do you know alternatives to achieve this goal? I was also thinking of subclassing Scheduler interface by myself, but it seems not so easy to gather all the necessary methods overriding.

Answer (score 1):

I recommend [celery-redbeat](https://github.com/sibson/redbeat) as it is a scheduler used in production by many companies.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. The one thing it seems missing in the package is de-scheduling of runtime-added tasks. The dirty way is acting directly on redis DB

Comment: Found a way! `RedBeatSchedulerEntry.from_key(my_key, my_celery_app).delete()`